# breezejs - updating the cache from notifications

Tags: breeze

In my setup I am getting signalr notifications from the server when entity is changed, for performance issues - on the notifications there is all the change track on the changed entity so I can update it without going to the server, how can i commit the changes on the entitymanager? as I am using Angular to bind to the cache, so i cannot replace the entity
is it via setUnchanged()?

Comment: Why not just update the entity and call acceptChanges on it?

Answer (score 1):

PW Kad has the right answer.Just update the entity in place and call *EntityAspect.acceptChanges* on it.  If your notification returns a javascript object, then you should create an *EntityKey* that identifies this object, use the *EntityKey* to locate the existing object in the EntityManager local cache, update it and then call *acceptChanges*.  Something like this

```
function mergeFromNotification(entityManager, notificationEntity) {
   // you will need to write 'extractEntityKey'
   var entityKey = extractEntityKey(notificationEntity);
   var existingEntity = entityManager.getEntityByKey(entityKey);
   // updates existingEntity with data from notificationEntity
   breeze.core.extend(existingEntity, notificationEntity);
   existingEntity.entityAspect.acceptChanges() ;

}
```